# Why do some variable declarations have "pale" colors?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I would like to know why some variable declarations in a class module get a pale color in VS2017.

[image]

When I hover the mouse for example over the "_sTitle" declaration, it suggests "Use automatically generated properties".

Is that why VS2017 makes it pale?

When I click to perform the suggestion, it turns my existing code

```
Public Property Title() As String
    Get
        Return _sTitle
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _sTitle = value
    End Set
End Property
```

into this:

```
Public Property Title() As String
= String.Empty
```

which of course won't compile.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know about VS, but in IntelliJ this happens when variables are just declared, not used in the code.

Comment: It's the same in VS.